# Removing a smooth weight

Tags: analysis, number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory

If I understand $$\sum _{n\leq x}a_n(1-n/x)\hspace {5mm}\text {or}\hspace {5mm}\sum _{n\leq x}a_n\log (x/n)$$ then I understand $$\sum _{n\leq x}a_n$$ by writing
$$\sum _{n\leq x}a_n=\frac {x+h}{h}\sum _{n\leq x+h}a_n(1-n/(x+h))-\frac {x}{h}\sum _{n\leq x}a_n(1-n/x)+\mathcal O(h)$$ and $$\sum _{n\leq x}a_n\int _x^{x+h}\frac {dt}{t}=\int _x^{x+h}\frac {1}{t}\left (\sum _{n\leq t}a_n\right )dt+\mathcal O(h)=\sum _{n\leq x+h}a_n\log ((x+h)/x)=\sum _{n\leq x+h}a_n\log ((x+h)/n)-\sum _{n\leq x}a_n\log (x/n)+\mathcal O(h).$$
Another common choice of weight is $e^{-n/x}$. But how do I link $$\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_ne^{-n/x}$$ sum to the unweighted sum?

(If I just want an upper bound I'm ok, but let's say I want an asymptotic. Also notice partial summation doesn't work, because the end-point change (the weights are no longer smooth)).

I've tried a few things like seeing what Taylor expansions of things like $e^{n/(x+h)$ give but I think really I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: This is one of the prototypical "Tauberian problems" (named after Tauber). This particular example falls under what is commonly called Tauber's second theorem. See the book "Tauberian Theory: A Century of Developments" by Korevaar for more. (The discussion near page 21 looks appropriate, but I didn't look much further). In practice, the story is that if one uses Dirichlet series techniques to understand the smoothed sum $\sum a(n) e^{-n/x}$, then one can use the same techniques to study sums with compactly supported smoothed functions, which are easier to work with.

Comment: Many thanks for this comment. I'm not sure if I'm completely understood, but it's definitely given me things to work with. Can I check if I'm at least half-understanding what you/they are saying? So: (I'm going to change the reference to the Montgomery/Vaughan book, sorry for the random change, it's just I could get the overview quicker from there, but ultimately it's through your reference). In Theorem 5.6, they are proving what I say in my question I can do - remove a Cesaro weight. Whilst in Theorem 5.7, they're doing what I ask in my question?

Comment: MV is an excellent book. Really, your question is exercise 5.2.20 in MV (except they write $\delta$ and you might write $1/x$). The solution of this exercise is very similar to the reasoning in Theorem 5.7 that you observe.

Comment: Ah, ye that's it. I guess I now "just" have to see what can come out when I apply the reasoning in Theorem 5.7 and Exercise 5.2.20 to my case. Again thank you for these specific references!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you assume for $a_n$. If $a_n\ge0$, then there is

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_ne^{-n/x}\ge\sum_{n\le x}a_ne^{-n/x}\ge e^{-1}\sum_{n\le x}a_n.
$$

Comment: but that can't give me an asymptotic (right?)

Comment: Yes, it does not yield asymptotic formula, but it is sufficient to deduce some deep results in number theory like [Siegel' theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.00635).